# Creating a Charles proxy alternative using Python

Tags: python, proxy, charles-proxy

I am using Charles proxy right now to monitor traffic between my devices and a website. The traffic is SSL and I am able to read it on charles. The issue is charles makes the content hard to read when I am filtering through hundreds of variables in s JSON object. I created a program that will filter the JSON after exporting the charles log. My next step is to get rid of charles completely and create my own proxy in python that can view http and https data. I was wondering if scapy or any other existing libraries existed that would work? I am interested with scapy because I can save the proxy log as a pcap file.

Comment: Have you seen this https://mitmproxy.org/ ?

Comment: I just checked it out. It seems like it would probably do what I want. It seems like it has a lot of features.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through mitmproxy would be overwhelming since it's a huge source base. If you would like to implement the proxy server from scratch. Here is what I learn during developing [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io)

1. Learn how to set up a tiny Proxy server: Basically, open the listening socket at your port (9090 for example). Accept any incoming requests and get the first line of the HTTP Message. It could be done a lightweight http-parser or any Python parser. The raw HTTP message looks like:

   CONNECT https://google.com HTTP/1.1
2. Parse and get the google and the IP: Open the socket connection to the destination IP and start to receive and sent forth and back from the client <-> the destination server.
3. The first step is essential to implement the HTTP Proxy in this step. Use http-parser to parse the rest of the HTTP Message. Thus, you can get the headers and body from the Request / Response -> Present to UI
4. Learn how HTTPS and SSL work: Use OpenSSL to generate a self-signed certificate and how to generate the chain certificates too.
5. Learn how to import those certificate to the macOS keychain by using security CLI or Security framework from Apple.
6. When you've done: it's time to start the HTTPS interception: Start the 2nd step and do SSL Handshake with appropriate certificate in both sides (Client -> Your Proxy Server and your Proxy Server -> Destination)
7. Parse the HTTP message as usual and get the rest of the message.

Overall, there are a lot of open sources out there, but I suggest to start from the simple version before moving on.

Hope that could help you.